# Android: Async task with editing views gives "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views" (HTTPGet freezes app)

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I am using Async to change the view of my activity so my screen does not freeze while it is loading. I am using HTTP get to get images, and this slows things down. I want the http get to run in the background and then change the layout after it finishes without freezing the app. Here is my code so far:

```
public class BackgroundStuff extends AsyncTask<Data,Integer, Long> {

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected Long doInBackground(Data... params) {
    params[0].activity.updateUIGameOne(params[0].data);
    publishProgress();
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Long aLong) {
    super.onPostExecute(aLong);
}
```

}

Where Data holds the value of the MainActivity instance (where the layout is changing) and the collection of the http get code instance.

This code (updateUIGameOne) runs while on the MainActivity but freezes the screen until it finishes the method.

Whenever I run the BackgoundStuff AsyncTast, I get the exception "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views"

How should I run this method that changes views in the background without freezing the screen?

Comment: First, do **not** reference the `Activity` from `doInBackground()`, as the activity instance may go away while the background thread is running. Move the `updateUIGameOne()` logic into `doInBackground()` itself and copy over data that the task needs. Second, with regard to the exception, that is because you are attempting to modify the UI from the thread that `doInBackground()` runs on. The point behind `AsyncTask` is to update the UI in `onPostExecute()` (or perhaps `onProgressUpdate()`). With regards to the freezing, we can't help you with that without seeing the `updateUIGameOne()` code.

Answer (score 1):

The error is fairly self-explanatory: everything you do in `doInBackground()` happens in a background thread. You can only update your UI from the main thread.

What you want to do is perform your long-running operations such as network requests in `doInBackground()`, then update your UI in `onPostExecute()`.

Comment: Seems legit. Only question though: In onPostExecute(), how do you define a variable as a, let's say, TextView, from the previous Activity?

Comment: I wouldn't reference your TextView inside your AsyncTask- you can call back to your Activity to tell the Activity to update with the data that you get in the background.

Answer (score -1):

You should put your UI code in runOnUiThread

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
    public void run() {
        updateUI();
    }
});
```